# Get file details and load image into spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a routine that prints all the files in a folder, the folder contains image files, they are icons. The script gets various details like Filename, Last Updated etc. I would like to add a column to the results which shows the actual icon. How can I do this.

Comment: did you try IMAGE function?

Comment: Where do you print it? Into a spreadsheet? You want to insert the actual icon into the spreadsheet?

Comment: yes so the sheet will have a role per file with various attributes adn one cell with the icon in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use the method [insertImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertimageblobsource,-column,-row)

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("XXXX");
  var blobSource = file.getBlob();
  var column = 1;
  var row = 1;
  sheet.insertImage(blobSource, column, row)
}
```